# Firebase static website hosting stop working "Site Not Found"

Tags: firebase, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

1. Need to rewrite the rules for some of the pages of my site. So I want to simply include my rewrites likes below.

Here is my firebase.json

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "mysite_id",
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/report/doc_view/**",
        "destination": "https://mynewsite.com/report/doc_view/**",
        "type": "302"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "*",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my last deployment status after 24 hours my site shows like below.

[image]

What should I need to update for my site up and ready?
Please tell me the reason why I am getting Site not found Error from Firebase.

2. Some of the backend services (like /cgi-bin/login.cgi) need to redirect from the Firebase-hosted site to mynewsite.com.

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "mysite_id",
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/report/doc_view/**",
        "destination": "https://mynewsite.com/report/doc_view/**",
        "type": "302"
      }
    ],
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/cgi-bin/login.cgi",
        "destination": "https://mynewsite.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi",
        "type": 301
      }
    ]
    "headers": [{
      "source": "*",
      "headers": [{
        "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value": "*"
      }]
    }, {
      "source": "**",
      "headers": [{
        "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value": "*"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

These kinds of rewrites may cause the above site not found errors. I am struggling with this point in production deployment. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrites in Firebase Hosting need to point to a path on the same website. From the documentation on [configuring rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites):

> **source** (recommended) or regex
> A URL pattern that, if matched to the initial request URL, triggers Hosting to apply the rewrite
>
> Use source to specify a glob (recommended).
> Use regex to specify a RE2 regular expression.
>
> **destination**
> A **local file** that must exist
>
> This URL can be a relative or an absolute path.

So the destination must be a local file, it cannot be a HTTP URL as you are trying to use.

If you want to send the users to that HTTP URL, you will have to put it in as a `redirect` not a `rewrite` rule.